# What is the easieset way to replace some missing key-caps for the AT&T 6300 keyboard?

Tags: keyboards, maintenance

I have an what appears to be an AT&T 6300 Computer.  It seems to work fine, but I am missing the F5, #7 and numpad + key caps on the keyboard.

[image]

What is the easiest way to find a replacement for the key-caps on the AT&T 6300 keyboard.

NOTE:  The replacement doesn't have to be original equipment for the 6300, it could be a 3rd party key-cap that happens to fit, or even something custom made or 3D-printed.  The preference however would be for a plastic cap that has the same look as the original.

Finding a 5.25" DOS 3.0 disk so I can complete booting is another story...

Comment: Ebay or you local random parts / old stuff store?

Comment: I think this type of question is covered by https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166/15334

Comment: @user3840170 This PC has a lot of unique/non standard cables and other parts.  I was hoping that someone knew something specifically about the mechanical details of the 6300 keyboard.  For example it would be really useful to know if the key-cap retaining clips were the same ones found on some other keyboards (either modern ones, or ones that were at least less old and easier to find in a parts store).

Comment: maybe consider a floppy to sd-card conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard pictured is an AT&T KBD301, which uses Olivetti dome with slider key switches.  [image: Olivetti dome with slider key switch detail.]  This keyboard was recently covered in a [YouTube video by Chyrosran22](https://youtu.be/c0Z9VdOu20w).  These are going to be difficult to source as its not a common switch and key caps from other switch types aren't compatible.

Other confirmed sources for compatible key caps are as follows:

Xerox 6060.[image: Xerox 6060 keyboard.]

Olivetti Personal Computer Keyboard 1 (ANK 2463) included with the Docutel/Olivetti Personal Computer M24.[image: Olivetti ANK 2463 keyboard.]

Olivetti Personal Computer Keyboard 2 (ANK 2462)[image: Olivetti ANK 2462 keyboard.]

Olivetti M20HD built in keyboard.[image: Olivetti M20HD computer.]

Olivetti M21 luggable computer keyboard.[image: Olivetti M21 luggable computer.]

Logabax Persona 1600 keyboard (rebranded 2462).[image: Logabax Persona 1600 keyboard.]

There may be compatibility with key caps from some other Olivetti key switch keyboards as well such as the Olivetti snap action switches as the key mounts look very similar, but I can't actually confirm that.  Examples of boards using these snap action switches would be the Olivetti L1 ANK 1426 and the built in keyboard of the Olivetti M20 computer.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the type of information I was looking for.  Do you know if there is anything like a mechanical drawing of the keys (either in the service manual, or some other public document)?  I mean, I am sure engineering drawings existed somewhere or they wouldn't have been able to make the thing to begin with.  I just hope that one survived and made its way into public view.

Comment: There's a diagram of the key switch mating surface in the patent diagrams, but unfortunately they don't show dimensions.  That's the best I've been able to find though.

https://patents.google.com/patent/EP0104956B1